# questions about python3.6 and tensorflow1.2

Tags: tensorflow

when i run a program, an error "Shape (10, ?) must have rank at least 3" appeared.
my code is below and maybe the error is "output,_=tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell,x_,dtype=tf.float32)"
however I cannot revise.
can you help me?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/yyb/PycharmProjects/untitled1/myLSTM.py", line 49, in <module>
    regressor.fit(train_X,train_y,batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,steps=TRAINING_STEPS)
  File "C:\Users\yyb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py", line 289, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\yyb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\learn\python\learn\estimators\estimator.py", line 439, in fit
    SKCompat(self).fit(x, y, batch_size, steps, max_steps, monitors)
  File "C:\Users\yyb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\learn\python\learn\estimators\estimator.py", line 1350, in fit
    monitors=all_monitors)
  File "C:\Users\yyb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py", line 289, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\yyb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\learn\python\learn\estimators\estimator.py", line 455, in fit
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn=input_fn, hooks=hooks)
  File "C:\Users\yyb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\learn\python\learn\estimators\estimator.py", line 955, in _train_model
    model_fn_ops = self._get_train_ops(features, labels)
  File "C:\Users\yyb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\learn\python\learn\estimators\estimator.py", line 1162, in _get_train_ops
    return self._call_model_fn(features, labels, model_fn_lib.ModeKeys.TRAIN)
  File "C:\Users\yyb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\learn\python\learn\estimators\estimator.py", line 1133, in _call_model_fn
    model_fn_results = self._model_fn(features, labels, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/yyb/PycharmProjects/untitled1/myLSTM.py", line 35, in lstm_model
    output,_=tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell,x_,dtype=tf.float32)
  File "C:\Users\yyb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\rnn.py", line 574, in dynamic_rnn
    dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\Users\yyb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\rnn.py", line 637, in _dynamic_rnn_loop
    for input_ in flat_input)
  File "C:\Users\yyb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\rnn.py", line 637, in <genexpr>
    for input_ in flat_input)
  File "C:\Users\yyb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_shape.py", line 649, in with_rank_at_least
    raise ValueError("Shape %s must have rank at least %d" % (self, rank))
ValueError: Shape (10, ?) must have rank at least 3


#coding=utf-8
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('Agg')
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt



learn=tf.contrib.learn

HIDDEN_SIZE=30    
NUM_LAYERS=2    
TIMESTEPS=10    
TRAINING_STEPS=10000    
BATCH_SIZE=32       
TRAINING_EXAMPLES=10000      
TESTING_EXAMPLES=1000    
SAMPLE_GAP=0.01      

def generate_data(seq):
    X=[]
    y=[]
    for i in range(len(seq)-TIMESTEPS-1):
        X.append([seq[i:i+TIMESTEPS]])
        y.append([seq[i+TIMESTEPS]])
    return np.array(X,dtype=np.float32),np.array(y,dtype=np.float32)

def lstm_model(X,y):
    lstm_cell=tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(HIDDEN_SIZE)
    cell=tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([lstm_cell]*NUM_LAYERS)

    x_=tf.unstack(X,axis=1)

    output,_=tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell,x_,dtype=tf.float32)

    output=output[-1]
    prediction,loss=learn.models.linear_regression(output,y)
    train_op=tf.contrib.layers.optimize_loss(loss,tf.contrib.framework.get_global_step(),optimizer="Adagrad",learning_rate=0.1)
    return prediction,loss,train_op

regressor=learn.Estimator(model_fn=lstm_model)

test_start=TRAINING_EXAMPLES*SAMPLE_GAP
test_end=(TRAINING_EXAMPLES+TESTING_EXAMPLES)*SAMPLE_GAP
train_X,train_y=generate_data(np.sin(np.linspace(0,test_start,TRAINING_EXAMPLES,dtype=np.float32)))
test_X,test_y=generate_data(np.sin(np.linspace(test_start,test_end,TESTING_EXAMPLES,dtype=np.float32)))

regressor.fit(train_X,train_y,batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,steps=TRAINING_STEPS)

predicted=[[pred] for pred in regressor.predict(test_X)]

rmse=np.sqrt(((predicted-test_y)**2).mean(axis=0))
print('Mean square error is: %f'%rmse[0])

fig=plt.figure()
plot_predicted=plt.plot(predicted,label='predicted')
plot_test=plt.plot(test_y,label='real_sin')
plt.legend([plot_predicted,plot_test],['predicted','real_sin'])
fig.savefig('sin.png')
```

Comment: Can we have the full stack trace please

Comment: the traceback is above

Comment: Looks like something you're sending to the fit function is the wrong shape. It says it should be rank 3 i.e. [x,y,z]. Perhaps you are not sending the correct data to it?

Comment: I try to reshape the input matrix to 3D,however,another error is that    ValueError: Trying to share variable rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/basic_lstm_cell/kernel, but specified shape (60, 120) and found shape (40, 120).

Comment: That error sounds like you've got your data shapes incorrect and are not reshaping correctly. I don't know much about lstm cells but if you visualise your graph in Tensorflow you can graphically see the shape of your data as it flows through the graph and you might be able to spot something wrong like that. Good luck

Comment: thanks！I will try again